# For every matrix $A$ and every positive real number $t$, the matrix $(AA^T + tI)$ is regular.

Tags: linear-algebra

For every matrix $A$ and every positive real number $t$, the matrix $(AA^T + tI)$ is regular.

I have this questing in my linear algebra class and I can't seem to find the answer, is this claim true or false? Can you find counterexample or prove the statement?

Comment: Do you mean for EYE identity matrix and for REGULAR invertible?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Have you learned anything in your course about the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of matrices of the form $AA^T$? ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix#Positive-semidefiniteness )

Comment: If $A$ is not real, the statement is false. E.g. $i^2+1=0$.

Comment: Let us call $B$ your matrix. Just calculate $x^T B x$ for any vector $x$

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $A$ (of type $n\times m,~m\le n$) is even positive definite: for any $x \neq 0$ one gets $x^{\text{T}}(AA^{\text{T}}+tI)x=\underbrace{||A^{\text{T}}x||^2}_{\ge 0}+\underbrace{t||x||^2}_{>0}>0.$